# How can I call a method on multiple objects in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am working with an XAML GUI created in VisualStudio, and I am trying to set up some of the code for the checkboxes. Instead of doing each one separately, I was hoping to do it dynamically since the functions are all the same.

I have searched, but was only able to find a reference to an Invoke-Method function that was written.

Below is what I have so far, just to explain better what I am trying to accomplish.

The Get-Variable line comes back with a half-dozen variables that I am trying to call the same method on.

```
$vars = Get-Variable WPFVarA*
Foreach ( $var in $vars ) {
    $var.Add_Checked.Invoke({$Global:TicketCount++})
    $var.Add_Unchecked.Invoke({$Global:TicketCount--})
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result and what error or undesired result is produced by your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the checkboxes are wrapped, say with a stackpanel (could be anything) you can create a routed even handler to handle all events, like this (untested):

```
#Bubble up event handler
[Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$Script:CheckedEventHandler = {
    $Global:TicketCount++
}
[Windows.RoutedEventHandler]$Script:UncheckedEventHandler = {
    $Global:TicketCount--
}

$StackPanel.AddHandler([Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::CheckedEvent, $CheckedEventHandler)
$StackPanel.AddHandler([Windows.Controls.CheckBox]::UncheckedEvent, $UncheckedEventHandler)
```